# Check asio already installed and find location

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

I want to include asio library to my software as in the below:

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/steady_timer.hpp>
```

I am using ubuntu. How do i know if the asio library already installed?
Also i guess i need to write below command to compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -I -pthread
```

With the -I, i need to provide asio location. Also how do i know the library location of asio?
I searched in the google but i didnt found anything.

Comment: Your compiler should look for include files in standard install locations. If it doesn't find asio, it is not installed.

Comment: @VLL i am using command line to compile, how do i include all standart install locations

Comment: @EyeOfTiger Standard locations are included by default (that's what makes them standard).

Comment: @EyeOfTiger Use ubuntu's package manager (called apt I think) to see if anything related to asio is installed. If not then find out the package name and install it using `apt`

Comment: @EyeOfTiger asio can also be distributed as part of the boost library. If that is the case for you then you should try `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`. That also might work.

Comment: after i installed asio using apt command, i am able to compile my codes without specifing -I. Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the ASIO library is already installed on your Ubuntu system, you can use the `dpkg` package manager. Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
dpkg -l libasio-dev
```

If ASIO is installed, you will see information about the package, including its version and description. If it is not installed, you will get a message saying the package is not found.

If ASIO is not installed, you can install it using the package manager. Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libasio-dev
```

This will download and install the ASIO library and its development files on your system.

Regarding the compilation command, you need to provide the path to the ASIO header files using the `-I` option. If ASIO is installed on your system, you don't need to specify the path explicitly. The compiler will automatically find the headers in the default include directories.

So, your compilation command should look like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

You don't need to add `-I` in this case, as the compiler will automatically find the ASIO headers if the library is installed on your system. The `-pthread` option is needed because ASIO uses threads for asynchronous operations.

After successful installation, you can simply include the ASIO header in your code as follows:

```cpp
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/steady_timer.hpp>
```

The compiler will find the headers in the default include directories, and you should be able to compile your code without any issues.